# Config File on Bluestack Mac, two taps at one key

Tags: android, config, bluestacks

I learned how to create a config file, and edit it. Here's my key.

```
[Keys]
Up          = Tap (13,63)
Down        = Tap (13,90)
Left        = Tap (6,75)
Right       = Tap (20,75)

1       = Tap (83,82)
2       = Tap (94,82)
3       = Tap (99,12)
4       = Tap (81,22)
5       = Tap (90,22)
6       = Tap (97,22)
7       = Tap (81,22)
8       = Tap (90,22)
9       = Tap (97,22)
0       = Tap (99,12)
```

But my goal is,

```
When I press "4", it taps (81,22) and (99,12) at once
```

or,

```
When I press "0", it loops to tap (99,12)
```

.